# Xamarin. Datagrid display works in debug but doesn't work in release mode

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have a datagrid in my page which shows data after a display button is pressed.
Code in my xaml:

```
<DGrd:DataGrid Grid.Row="1"
                ItemsSource="{Binding LeaveBalances}"
                SelectionEnabled="False" HeaderLabelStyle="{StaticResource HeaderlabelStyle}">
                <DGrd:DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DGrd:DataGridColumn Title="Leave" PropertyName="LeaveName" />
                    <DGrd:DataGridColumn Title="Opening" PropertyName="Opening" StringFormat="{}{0:N1}" />
                    <DGrd:DataGridColumn Title="Availed" PropertyName="Availed" StringFormat="{}{0:N1}" />
                    <DGrd:DataGridColumn Title="Balance" PropertyName="Balance" StringFormat="{}{0:N1}" />
                </DGrd:DataGrid.Columns>
            </DGrd:DataGrid>
```

My Viewmodel:

```
private async Task RefreshView()
        {
            BusyStatus = "Loading Leave Balance";
            await InvokeAsync(() => oLeaveService.GetCurrentLeaveYear(), (lvYear) => { LeaveYear = lvYear; });
            await InvokeAsync(() => oLeaveService.GetEmpLeaveBalance(User.CurrentUser.PKID), LeaveBalanceGet_Completed);
        }
```

My application works fine in debug mode. But the button doesn't give any response in release mode.
What can I do in this matter ?

P.S. : I have tried making the linker properties none in release mode. But in that case my archiving fails.

Answer (score 1):

Just found out I was using styling in my datagrid which resulted it not giving any response in release mode. No idea why.
It works fine after I commented out this part:

```
<Style TargetType="DGrd:DataGrid">
                <Setter Property="FontFamily">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                            <OnPlatform.iOS>Lato-Regular</OnPlatform.iOS>
                            <OnPlatform.Android>Lato-Regular.ttf#Lato-Regular</OnPlatform.Android>
                            <OnPlatform.WinPhone>Assets/Fonts/Lato-Regular.ttf#Lato</OnPlatform.WinPhone>
                        </OnPlatform>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="HeaderHeight" Value="50" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15" />
                <Setter Property="HeaderFontSize" Value="15" />
                <Setter Property="HeaderBackground" Value="{x:Static constants:SystemColors.ListHeaderBackColor}" />
                <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="{x:Static constants:SystemColors.GridBorderColor}" />
            </Style>
```